# Using bitset in place of using hand written bit manipulation code?

Tags: c++, stl, bit-manipulation, bit, bitset

Is there any performance loss/gain using bitset in place where hand written?

How to build the following using a bitset at runtime

- make all the bits between 2 and 5 as zero i.e., `11110011`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution to your second question would be to use another bitset.

```
void makebitszero(bitset<8>& b) {
  // Everything but bits 3 and 4 (between 2 and 5).
  static const bitset<8> mask = ~bitset<8>(12);
  b &= mask;
}
```

It takes a bit of math to come up with an expression for `mask` given two bit positions.

[edit]
Ok, here's the math. The trick is that `(1UL << X) -1` is a sequence of `X` ones. E.g. 3 => 00000111.
Hence, (1<<5) - (1<<3) = 00011111 - 00000111 -1 + 1 = 00011000 (bits 3 and 4). Thus in code:

```
template<int i, int j, int N> 
void makeBitsZero(bitset<N>& b) {
  // Everything from bit i up to but not including bit j (i < j)
  static const bitset<N> mask = ~bitset<N>(1UL<<j) - (1UL<<i));
  b &= mask;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The golden rule:

**Don't optimise prematurely!**

Bitset will in 99% of cases, be fast *enough*, and has the advantage of being a common concept such that it's both more readable, and less prone to implementation errors.  Don't simply assume that your code will obviously need the speed increase; write the code using bitset, profile your application, and see if:

1. It's fast enough as it is; and
2. If it's not fast enough, does it really spend the majority of its time doing bit operations?

Per the 80-20 rule, chances are that you'll get a much greater return on making some other bit of code faster.  And hey, if it turns out that you do need to improve the bit-twiddling speed, at least you have some decent baseline figures to use in order to show that you r solution really is faster than the default (which you'd need anyway if you wanted to optimise for performance).

Answer (score 0):

For a simple example such as the above, a decent hand-coded solution will be faster than using bitset, but the performance differences in either case would be small.